# "too much recursion" error with live handlers in jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is similar to [my last question about "too much recursion" errors in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639862/too-much-recursion-error-in-jquery-1-3-2), but involving live handlers. I have one element within another. Both of them have custom event handlers with the same name. The outer element has a traditional handler and the inner element has a live handler. When I try to trigger the event on the outer element, my browser pauses for a while, then I get an error saying "too much recursion".

I read on the [live handler documentation page](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) that I can prevent bubbling of a live handler by returning false within the handler function. However, I tried this and it doesn't seem to make a difference. Either way, the outer function seems to somehow be called many times when I am trying to call it only once.

How can I fix this? Is it possible to have handlers with the same name like this, or do I have to come up with different names? You can test the problem using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>live event handler test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#outer").bind("test", function() {
    $("#inner").trigger("test");
});

$("#inner").live("test", function() {
    return false;
});

$(function() {
    $("#outer").trigger("test");
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Nice complete test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `#outer`'s callback:

```
$("#outer").bind("test", function() {
    $("#inner").trigger("test");
});
```

You are triggering `"test"`on `#inner`, but *`#inner` is a child of `#outer`*, so the event "bubbles up" to `#outer` and the whole process repeats itself (until it blows up).

**Edit**: as @Seth points out, if you use `live()` on both `#outer` and `#inner` it works. That's because `"return false;"` works like [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopImmediatePropagation.28.29) in that case. Likewise, if you use `bind()` on both it also works. That's because `"return false;"` works like [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29) in that case.

However you are mixing both and using `bind` on `#outer` and `live` on `#inner`. Net effect is that triggering your event as I pointed out will never execute your `live` handler (i.e. `return false` never gets executed) because [it is bound to the `document`](http://www.zachleat.com/web/2009/05/08/performance-caveat-with-jquery-selectors-and-live-events/), and the event never get a chance to bubble up to the `document` due to the stack overflow.

**Edit 2**:

> Is there a way to prevent the bubbling on the inner event? (using `live()`?)

Nope. See [jquery Event.stopPropagation() seems not to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122375/jquery-event-stoppropagation-seems-not-to-work) a better explanation.

Comment: Why does the event on #inner bubble up to #outer? Isn't the "return false" statement supposed to prevent that?

Comment: Why is there a stack overflow? If the live handler never gets executed, I don't see why the outer function would get called more than once.

Comment: @mikez302: `trigger` bubbles. Simple as that. Remove `live` and the problem still exists. `live` has nothing to do with it. The wording of my last paragraph is confusing the issue I think. The problem is still what I state in the first paragraph.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the bubbling on the inner event?

Comment: @mikez302: yes, use `bind()` for `#inner` rather than `live()`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for live events?

Comment: @mikez302: Nope. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122375/jquery-event-stoppropagation-seems-not-to-work

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the combination of live and bind for a custom event has a bug in it?  Not quite sure what is going on actually.  If you only use live it works:

```
$("#outer").live("test", function() {
    console.log("outer");
    $("#inner").trigger("test");
});

$("#inner").live("test", function() {
     console.log("inner");
    return false;
});

$(function() {
    $("#outer").trigger("test");
});
```

Haven't dug into the source too much but it seems like `bind` ignores the return value of the function.

Comment: Really? I tried changing the "test" names to "click" and I am getting the exact same error.