# jquery - Too Much Recursion

Tags: jquery, recursion, click

The code below isn't working and is returning a recursion error.  I looked through a few of the other posts here, and saw one in particular (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639862/too-much-recursion-error-in-jquery-1-3-2) I thought would help me out, and I adjusted my code, but guess I'm not getting the principle because I'm still getting the error...

```
//Note - can't use radios... must use checkboxes

$('div.divCheck').click(function() {
       var testEv = $(this).find('input').attr("id");
       $(this).children('div').toggleClass('selected');
       $("input#"+testEv).click();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="divCheck clearfix">
   <div class="checkboxArea1 unselected">
        <input type="checkbox" id="pqrs">
        <label class="filterlabel pqrCheckbox">PQR</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you're using jQuery for recursion. You should totally drop that and ... Oh, wait...

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering event bubbling.  Do you have a function bound to the click event of the CheckBox already?  It looks like the click event to the CheckBox is bubbling back up to the div that contains it, which is causing circular recursion.  I would look into changing the last line of the div click handler to something like `$('input#' + testEv).attr('checked', 'checked');`.  You may also be able to use StopPropagation in the click handler for the CheckBox.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the click event is propagating up the DOM tree, and therefore the click event handler is calling itself, causing the error. Try this out:

```
$('div.divCheck').click(function(e) {
   var testEv = $(this).find('input').attr("id");
   $(this).children('div').toggleClass('selected');
   $("input#"+testEv).click();
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I suspected as much because of the other post, and I tried variations of "stopPropagation" and `return false;` but I'm still getting a recursion error... This is the latest iteration that didn't work... `$('div.divCheck').click(function() {     var testEv = $(this).find('input').attr("id");     $('input#' + testEv).click();     return false;          $('input#' + testEv).click(function(e) {      e.stopPropagation();   });      $(this).children('div').toggleClass('selected');   });`

Comment: I should also say that I copied and pasted your code (that was the first iteration), and it didn't prevent the recursion error either..

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to get the checkbox checked you can use the jQuery `prop` function.

```
$('div.divCheck').click(function() {
       var testEv = $(this).find('input').attr("id");
       $(this).children('div').toggleClass('selected');
       var $elm = $("input#"+testEv);
       $elm.prop('checked', !$elm.prop('checked'));
});
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rq8amj5j/)